# Checking if a statement is a Taututology

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I have this question

[image]

As per http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/

This statment is not a tautuology.So is the question wrong?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using tool you don't understand how to use. RTFM and write "(P->Q)->(Q->R)->(P or Q->R)" instead into your tool. The expression you entered have four independent atoms P, PvQ, Q and R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row $5$ has $P$ and $Q$ set to false, and $P\lor Q$ set to true. That's not possible.

Also, clarify whether $a\implies b\implies c$ mean $$(a\implies b)\implies c$$ or $$a\implies (b\implies c)$$
because they are not the same.

To get proof that you have a tautology, insert

```
(P->R) -> (Q->R) -> ((P\/Q) -> R)
```

into the webpage you listed.

Comment: You were faster than I was! haha +1

Comment: @5xum On trying to solve manually first i need to write the truth values for the triple.By using 2^3 i understand that there a 8 possible values.But how can i write these values easily.is there an easy way?

Comment: @techno Is writing $8$ possible values not an easy way?

Comment: @5xum Yeah.But how can i easy write the triplet pattern?Is there an easy way to follow?

Comment: @techno Yes. The last column goes $TFTFTFTF\dots$. The column before that goes $TTFFTTFFTTFF\dots$. The one before that goes $TTTTFFFFTTTTFFFF\dots$. If you continue with more variables, the next one has $8$ repetitions of $T$ and $8$ of $F$, then $16$, then $32$,\dots

Comment: @5xum Hmm. i think you misunderstood my question.What i was asking for is this- we write the truth values for the triplet P,Q and R first.Like i know there are 8 values.So first i write TTT then i replace first T by F and write FTT and so on.But i find it time consuming to check whether i have repeated any pattern and also i think i waste some time to compute unique triplet pattern.What i was asking is,is there a way to just write it off in some easy way.

Comment: @techno I know. And that's what I wrote. Because if you follow what I did, you wil get $TTT$ in the first row, then $TTF$ in the second, then $TFT$ in the third row and so on.  I just told you how to write columns instead of rows because that's easier to remember.

Comment: @5xum okay:) got that now,im little slow to grasp.So if it get 4 variables i will write an additional first column with 8pairs of T and and F each.

Comment: @5xum Thanks a lot.Missed that.